# Get Icon URL and filename of document library file using JSOM in office 365 app

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, app, client-object-model

I have an app that includes a Document Library...using my normal code to display the list but keep getting a null on the field...i've tried

```
rptDocsListItem1.get_item("xd_ProgID")
```

and

```
rptDocsListItem1.get_item("title")
```

and

```
rptDocsListItem1.get_item("Name")
```

but each of them returns a null?? Am i missing something? Full code below.

```
// This function shows Country Limits table
function getdocLibrary() {
var rptDocs = document.getElementById("docsList");
rptDocsList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Document Library');
var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
var rptDocsListItems = rptDocsList.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(rptDocsListItems);
context.executeQueryAsync(

    function () {
        // Success returned from executeQueryAsync

        if (rptDocsListItems.get_count() > 0) {
            var rptDocsListItemEnumerator1 = rptDocsListItems.getEnumerator();

            // Lets get the select items
            while (rptDocsListItemEnumerator1.moveNext()) {
                var rptDocsListItem1 = rptDocsListItemEnumerator1.get_current();
                $("#docsList").append("<li><strong><a href='javascript:;' >" + rptDocsListItem1.get_item("xd_ProgID") + "</a></strong></li>");
            }


            $('#tblDocLibrary').show();

        }
        else { $('#tblNoDocLibrary').show(); $('#tblDocLibrary').hide(); }

    },
    function (sender, args) {
        // Failure returned from executeQueryAsync
        alert("Error in News: " + args.get_message());
    }
    );

}
```

Comment: have you loaded the item?

Comment: Yes they are loaded. I did not include all the code...original post updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

### How to retrieve properties for Document Library items?

Since some properties are stored in File object, specify File client object explicitly  in `ClientContext.Load` method:

```
context.load(items,"Include(File)");
```

then, you could get properties like this:

```
var file = item.get_file();

var title = file.get_title();
var name = file.get_name();
```

### Example

```
function getDocuments(title) {
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web(); 

   var docLibrary = web.get_lists().getByTitle(title);
   var items = docLibrary.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
   context.load(items,"Include(File)");
   context.executeQueryAsync(
     function () {

        if (items.get_count() > 0) {
            var e = items.getEnumerator();
            while (e.moveNext()) {
                var item = e.get_current();
                var file = item.get_file();

                var title = file.get_title();
                var name = file.get_name();


            }

        }
     },
     function (sender, args) {
        console.log("Error in News: " + args.get_message());
     }
     );
}

getDocuments('Documents');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

The following link includes all the "real" column names for a document library, very handy.

[Reference list for SharePoint internal field names](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx)

The code should read.

```
rptDocsListItem1.get_item("FileLeafRef")
```